# How to avoid the use of mutable datastructure and use more functional approach?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I'm building in scheme a database using a wiredtiger key/value store.

To query a given table one needs to have a `cursor` over the table. The library recommends to re-use the `cursor`. The general behavior can be described by the following pseudo-code:

```
with db.cursor() as cursor:

   cursor.get(key)

   ...

   do_something(db)
   ...
```

During the extent of the `with` statment `cursor` **can only** be used in the current context. If `do_something(db)` needs a cursor, it must create/retrieve another cursor even if it's to query the same table. Otherwise the `cursor` loose its position and the continuation of `do_something(db)` doesn't expect.

You can work around it by *always reseting* the cursor, that's a waste. Instead it's preferable to keep a set of cursors ready to be used and when one can *request* via `db.cursor()` this will remove a cursor from the available cursors and return it. Once the "context" operation is finished, put it back.

The way I solve this in Python is by using a `list`. `db.cursor()` looks like:

```
def cursor(self):
    cursor = self.cursors.pop()
    yield cursor
    self.cursors.append(cursor)
```

Which means, retrieve a cursor, send it to the current context, once the context is finished, put it back to the list of available cursors.

How can I avoid the mutation and use more functional approach?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want parameters?

Lookup the exact construct used by your Scheme implementation.

Some implementations use:

```
http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-39/srfi-39.html
```

Comment: can you be more precise?

Comment: There are nice description of parameters here: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/parameterize.html  The last sections compare parameters with mutation.